# PHP - MENU_LOCAL_TASK in Drupal

Tags: routes

How do I add #markup or #suffix to MENU_LOCAL_TASK in Drupal?

```
$items['user/%/checkins_history'] = array( //add to to user's profile
            'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
            'title' => t('Checkins History'),           
            'suffix' => '<div>Num'.$num_of_results .'</div>', // NOT WORKING            
            'access arguments' => array('Administer Checkins'),
            'page arguments' => array(1),
            'file' => 'manager.inc',
            'page callback' => 'manager_checkins_history_page'
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking doesn't really make sense.

`MENU_LOCAL_TASK` is used as metadata for a route defined in `hook_menu()`.

`#prefix` and `#suffix` are properties for render arrays.

The two concepts are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Your calling this from hook_menu, correct? I don't believe that suffix can be used from here. At least it's not in the list of valid return values in listed on the [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) page.

You'll need to add the suffix to whatever the output of your url is, if it's a form, it can nicely be added to the form via the form api.

Example:

Let's say your function `manager_checkins_history_page` is a form that uses the form aip, and looks something like this:

```
function manager_checkins_history_page($form, &$form_state){

  $form['switch'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('i'm a chekcbox'),
    '#default_value' => false,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

if you wanted to apply a suffix to the whole form, you could do something like:

```
function manager_checkins_history_page($form, &$form_state){
  $form['group1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Your Name'),
    '#suffix' => "I'm a suffix for your form",  
   );

  $form['group1']['switch'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('i'm a chekcbox'),
    '#default_value' => false,
  );

  $form['group1']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

That would give you a form, wrapped in a box, with a suffix at the end.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: @Grasper, check out my edit. Again, I'm working under the assumption that this looks like an edit page for checkins, and if that's the case might be a form call back. If that is incorrect, please post your call back function to get a better answer. The long and short of it is, hook_menu sets up the page callbacks, and the content should be provided in the callback, so your suffix should be coming from there.

Comment: drupal is just a mess...compared to WP. The tab only displays data, no form inside. I hate drupal with all my heart, lol

Comment: Ok, in that case you should just be able to append the content of your suffix to the return value of manager_checkins_history_page. so you don't really need '#suffix' in this case. And drupal has a bit of a learning curve, so don't get too flustered. That's why we're here ;)

Comment: @Grasper are you trying to add a suffix as a means to work around Drupal's plaintext title restriction? There's other ways to skin that cat.

Comment: @Grasper If you're new to Drupal, you probably will hate it :) It's far superior to Wordpress in every respect (with the obvious exception of blogging, where Wordpress shines above all others), but that superiority comes at the price of a steeper learning curve. If you stick with it I can guarantee you'll be calling Wordpress a 'mess' compared to Drupal in no time at all

Comment: ok, so tell me how do I enable html in 'title' => t('Checkins History '). '<b>' . $num_of_results . '</b>' , there is no way.

Comment: @Grasper drupal cleans html from titles to prevent xss vulnerabilities. There are a few work-arounds that you might be able to try, like https://www.drupal.org/node/28537, which would require some template tweaking.

Comment: see! And this is why I hate Drupal, makes everything over complicated.